# Any idea why the data in my DbInitializer is not populating in my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Using SQL Server Express LocalDB, the data I've coded in the `DbInitializer` is not being populated into my database. I'm not sure if it's lazy loading or if there is something missing that's causing the data not to seed.

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using FinesJune.Models;

namespace FinesJune.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        // The Fines table
        public DbSet<Fine> Fines { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `DbInitializer` class, where the data is written to be coded in the database upon seeding:

```
using FinesJune.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace FinesJune.Data
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            // Seed roles
            // Get the Identity Role Manager from services
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            // Create each role
            roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole() { Name = "Traffic Manager" }).Wait();
            roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole() { Name = "Traffic Officer" }).Wait();
            roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole() { Name = "Driver" }).Wait();

            // Add the test users (one for each role). Employs the usermanager service.
            // Driver test user
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            userManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser()
            {
                Email = "driver@testwebsite.com",
                UserName = "driver@testwebsite.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false
            }).Wait();
            // Get the user from the DB
            IdentityUser driverUser = userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == "driver@testwebsite.com");
            // Give it a password and the appropriate role
            userManager.AddPasswordAsync(driverUser, "Pa$$word1").Wait();
            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(driverUser, "Driver").Wait();

            // Officer test user
            userManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser()
            {
                Email = "officer@testwebsite.com",
                UserName = "officer@testwebsite.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false
            }).Wait();
            // Get the user from the DB
            IdentityUser officerUser = userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == "officer@testwebsite.com");
            // Give it a password and the appropriate role
            userManager.AddPasswordAsync(officerUser, "Pa$$word1").Wait();
            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(officerUser, "Traffic Officer").Wait();

            // Manager test user
            userManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser()
            {
                Email = "manager@testwebsite.com",
                UserName = "manager@testwebsite.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false
            }).Wait();
            // Get the user from the DB
            IdentityUser managerUser = userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == "manager@testwebsite.com");
            // Give it a password and the appropriate role
            userManager.AddPasswordAsync(managerUser, "Pa$$word1").Wait();
            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(managerUser, "Traffic Manager").Wait();

            // Seed fines
            var fine = new Fine[]
            {
                new Fine {
                    FineID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    OfficerID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DriverID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    LicensePlate = "CY4345",
                    VehicleType = VehicleType.Car,
                    Offense = OffenseType.Speeding,
                    OffenseDetail = "85km/h in a 60 zone.",
                    OffenseDate = DateTime.Parse("2017-08-10"),
                    OffenseTime = DateTime.Parse("05:50"),
                    Amount = 50.50m,
                    Outstanding = true
                },
                new Fine {
                    FineID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    OfficerID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DriverID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    LicensePlate = "CA323566",
                    VehicleType = VehicleType.Bus,
                    Offense = OffenseType.Parking,
                    OffenseDetail = "Parked on red line.",
                    OffenseDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-20"),
                    OffenseTime = DateTime.Parse("16:20"),
                    Amount = 350.00m,
                    Outstanding = true
                },
                new Fine {
                    FineID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    OfficerID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DriverID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    LicensePlate = "CY198450",
                    VehicleType = VehicleType.Car,
                    Offense = OffenseType.Speeding,
                    OffenseDetail = "140km/h in a 100 zone.",
                    OffenseDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-03-12"),
                    OffenseTime = DateTime.Parse("09:15"),
                    Amount = 500.00m,
                    Outstanding = true
                },
                new Fine {
                    FineID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    OfficerID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DriverID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    LicensePlate = "CA321",
                    VehicleType = VehicleType.Motorcycle,
                    Offense = OffenseType.Speeding,
                    OffenseDetail = "65km/h in a 40 zone.",
                    OffenseDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-10-19"),
                    OffenseTime = DateTime.Parse("15:00"),
                    Amount = 250.00m,
                    Outstanding = true
                },
                new Fine {
                    FineID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    OfficerID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DriverID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    LicensePlate = "CA974039",
                    VehicleType = VehicleType.Car,
                    Offense = OffenseType.DUI,
                    OffenseDetail = "DUI of alcohol.",
                    OffenseDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-11"),
                    OffenseTime = DateTime.Parse("10:10"),
                    Amount = 650.80m,
                    Outstanding = false
                },
                new Fine {
                    FineID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    OfficerID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DriverID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    LicensePlate = "CY936503",
                    VehicleType = VehicleType.Car,
                    Offense = OffenseType.Parking,
                    OffenseDetail = "Illegally parked on corner.",
                    OffenseDate = DateTime.Parse("2015-06-21"),
                    OffenseTime = DateTime.Parse("11:41"),
                    Amount = 250.00m,
                    Outstanding = true
                },
                new Fine {
                    FineID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    OfficerID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    DriverID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    LicensePlate = "CA99840",
                    VehicleType = VehicleType.Truck,
                    Offense = OffenseType.Speeding,
                    OffenseDetail = "100km/h in a 60 zone.",
                    OffenseDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-06-21"),
                    OffenseTime = DateTime.Parse("09:55"),
                    Amount = 1500.00m,
                    Outstanding = true
                },
            };
            // Add fines into the in-memory context, then save that context's changes into the DB
            foreach (Fine f in fine)
            {
                context.Fines.Add(f);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using FinesJune.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FinesJune
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            // Set the service scope
            var services = host.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;

            /* Will run if the context has not yet been created, meaning data is seeded only once.
             * Add an '!' to the boolean of this if statement to force a rerun. */
            if (services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .Database.EnsureCreated())
            {
                CreateDbIfNotExists(host);
            }

            // Run the host...
            host.Run();
        }
        private static void CreateDbIfNotExists(IHost host)
        {
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    // Get the context and send it into the DB seed method
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    DbInitializer.Seed(context, services);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred creating the DB.");
                }
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FinesJune.Data;


namespace FinesJune
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            // Note that the .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() method is used here to ensure the rolemanager is available in services.
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried rebuilding, restarting, and ran the web application but the database does not get seeded with the data defined in the `DbInitializer`.
**Edit**: I found that adding the code in the `DbInitializer` to the Index method in the `Home Controller`, the data was seeded to the database

Comment: Well, do some basic debugging. Nice seed method there. IS IT EVER CALLED? We would sort of, you know, expect that before spending our time, as debugging. Just a nice little assert or breakpoint and you know.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following URL might help you.

[Seed data EF core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding)